In an ASP.NET web forms project (.NET Framework) how do I simply concatenate scripts together, preferably also minify them, and do this at build time?
I have an ASP.NET Web Application and a bunch of legacy scripts that are being bundled together using the Visual Studio "Bundler & Minifier" extension. These are just creating library files with a bunch of globally available library functions, some classes, etc.
The Bundler & Minifier works great. There's a bundleconfig.json and I just tell it which scripts I want bundled together and it just does it - as soon as I save a source file, the bundles are automatically generated.
The problem is that this is only done on the developer machines, not on the build server, so the dist files need to be included in the Git repository. This leads to conflicts.
I've been writing JavaScript for a long time, but not in the paradigm of client-side frameworks and npm. It's been pages with a reference to a js file - a lot of jQuery to manipulate stuff and some of our newer stuff uses Vue 2, but currently no component files (.vue), it's just all in script. We only recently dropped support for IE11, so we weren't even able to use ES2015 stuff until then.
I've been looking into WebPack and Vite, since I'd also like to be able to also use .vue files and have those compiled as well, but they seem very tied to using modules, which would be a huge refactoring of my scripts. Hot reload during development sounds nice, but is not essential.
Webpack had a webpack-merge-and-include-globally plug-in which seemed like it would do what I wanted, but it hasn't been updated in 4 years and doesn't seem to work anymore.
I just want to concatenate a bunch of files and minify the output. Preferably create both the minified and unminified file as outputs. I'd also prefer if it worked with scss, since we have a bunch of those as well that are being compiled using the Web Compiler extension.
I would prefer this would happen right when I save the file, but also on build, and it would have to be runnable by a build server in CI/CD.
There's a similar question here (Is there a way to minify css files at build time?), but the answer is from 2017 and uses Grunt/Gulp, which, as far as I can tell aren't used much anymore, but if that's still the best way to go, I'm OK with that too.
I've spent a lot of time Googling for an answer, but the only answers are years old and don't work anymore.

You can compile sass at runtime using the Dart Sass CLI: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass/. The post build events are handy for this. If you can live with concatenating and minifying at application start-up you could try https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer
